# Replace characters in a string with whitespaces

Tags: python, string, replace, translate

I am writing a simple Python script that retrieves the latest tweet of any twitter user (in this case BBC) and uses the integrated text-to-speech system on Mac to read out the content of that particular tweet.

Everything is running as it should, but there are certain things I want to improve. For instance, if a tweet contains the character "#", the computer will speak this as "number". E.g, if the tweet were to read "#BBC covers the latest news", the computer speaks "number BBC covers the latest news".

I have declared a string to hold the content of the tweet, and wish to find a way to replace unwanted characters with white spaces. So far, I have the following:

```
for char in data_content: #data_content is the string holding the tweet
    if char in "#&/": # does not replace #
        mod_data = data_content.replace(char, '')
print(mod_data)
system('say ' + mod_data)
```

This seems to be working correctly with the "/" character, but does not replace the "#" character. So, any help on this matter is very much appreciated!

P.S. I have tried replacing the "#" character alone, in which case I get the desired result. However, when I try to provide a series of characters to replace, it only replaces the "/" character.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop always transforms data_content to mod_data so you will always only see the last change.

Say your string is `"#BBC covers the latest issues with G&F. See bbc.co.uk/gf"`

First time a char in your list is found is the `#` so:

`mod_data = "BBC covers the latest issues with G&F. See bbc.co.uk/gf"`

Next the `&` is found but it is found in data_content so the changes you made earlier are ignored and you get:

`mod_data = "#BBC covers the latest issues with GF. See bbc.co.uk/gf"`

The same happens when the `/` is found and you get:

`mod_data = "#BBC covers the latest issues with G&F. See bbc.co.ukgf"`

That's why it looks like it is only working for the `/`.

You can simply do what you want using regular expressions like this:

```
import re

string = "#BBC covers the latest issues with G&F. See bbc.co.uk/gf"
mod_data = re.sub(r"[#&/]", " ", string)
print(mod_data)
system('say ' + mod_data)
```

Comment: Aaaa, that makes a lot of sense. Thanks for pointing that out! 
Works like a charm now. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I have an additional suggestion. Since `replace()` works for all occurrences of the character in the string, you don't need that outer loop, so you could change your code to something like this:

```python
mod_data = data_content
for char in "#&/":
    mod_data = mod_data.replace(char, '')
```